# Cannot read property 'exports' of undefined

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm, webpack

I am currently experiencing a problem during a group work done in Angular.

Recently it is impossible to compile with `"ng serve"` but on the other hand the compilation works with `"ng serve --prod"`.
It seems that the problem comes from the version of typescript (exports instead of export). Unfortunately, I tried to change the versions on the system as well as in app.module.ts but without success.

Here is the complete error information:

> ERROR in : TypeError: Cannot read property 'exports' of undefined
>       at resolveNameHelper (/home/flavian/git3/Sigma2018/frontend/src/main/frontend/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:27546:70)
>       at resolveName (/home/flavian/git3/Sigma2018/frontend/src/main/frontend/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:27491:20)
>       at resolveEntityName (/home/flavian/git3/Sigma2018/frontend/src/main/frontend/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:28152:26)
>       at Object.getTypeReferenceSerializationKind (/home/flavian/git3/Sigma2018/frontend/src/main/frontend/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:47726:31)
>       at serializeTypeReferenceNode (/home/flavian/git3/Sigma2018/frontend/src/main/frontend/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:52219:30)
>       at serializeTypeNode (/home/flavian/git3/Sigma2018/frontend/src/main/frontend/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:52167:28)
>       at serializeTypeOfNode (/home/flavian/git3/Sigma2018/frontend/src/main/frontend/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:52039:28)
>       at serializeParameterTypesOfNode (/home/flavian/git3/Sigma2018/frontend/src/main/frontend/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:52074:42)
>       at addOldTypeMetadata (/home/flavian/git3/Sigma2018/frontend/src/main/frontend/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:51962:98)
>       at addTypeMetadata (/home/flavian/git3/Sigma2018/frontend/src/main/frontend/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:51953:17)
>       at transformAllDecoratorsOfDeclaration (/home/flavian/git3/Sigma2018/frontend/src/main/frontend/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:51792:13)
>       at generateConstructorDecorationExpression (/home/flavian/git3/Sigma2018/frontend/src/main/frontend/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:51902:40)
>       at addConstructorDecorationStatement (/home/flavian/git3/Sigma2018/frontend/src/main/frontend/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:51890:30)
>       at visitClassDeclaration (/home/flavian/git3/Sigma2018/frontend/src/main/frontend/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:51133:13)
>       at visitTypeScript (/home/flavian/git3/Sigma2018/frontend/src/main/frontend/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:50972:28)
>       at visitorWorker (/home/flavian/git3/Sigma2018/frontend/src/main/frontend/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:50785:24)

I come here in the hope that someone has a solution.

Comment: Please delete the  node_module folder then install all modules

Comment: Thank's @Shahid. 
I don't understand because I already tried to modify the versions of typescript. The project has always worked in 2.4.2. I tried to put the 3.4.2 in the package.json file and reinstalling it via npm install -g typescript@latest without success.
Finally reinstalling version 2.7.2 I don't have any problems without really understanding the reason.

Comment: if you want to update angular or typescript . angular 7 support typescript 3.1  please visit this site  https://update.angular.io/ they